# Exercises about Distributions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I'm looking for references (books or pdf) about the following themes (especially the first two) :

1. Fourier Series of Distributions.
2. Distributional solutions of ordinary differential equations.
3. Fourier Transform of Distributions.
4. Convolution of Distributions.
5. Tempered Distributions.

with exercises (with answers) : direct applications of the theory, simple problems with detailed questions.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could try

Claude Zuily, Problems in Distributions and Partial Differential Equations (North-Holland 1988).

Another book that might be of interest for you is

Duistermaat J., Kolk J. Distributions: Theory and Applications (Birkhäuser 2010).

Solutions to selected (starred) problems are given at the end of the book.

Comment: I've already look into this book, the exercises are too difficult (I was looking for direct applications of the theory) and sometimes there are too many references to others exercises. But thank you anyway.

Comment: And also, there is nothing about Fourier series of distributions.